# Python socket security

Tags: python, sockets, security

I plan to use socket (https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#example) to allow a simple software i'm writing to be clustered across multiple computers, and i'm wondering what security risks there are with using Socket. I know that open ports CAN be vulnerable depending on the software behind them, and I know how to cleanse input data and such to prevent buffer overflow type attacks and code injection, but are there any major security vulnerabilities using Socket? Is there a way to make it secure for prolonged use of the port?

I am just starting to delve into programming that involves networking, so if I have the wrong idea entirely please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Since the Python language takes care of all of the memory management and variable typing for us, buffer overflow vulnerabilities is off the table ( Unless python core vulnerabilities. For example; https://hackerone.com/reports/55017 )

Another major thing is Secure Socket Layer. You should use SSL on your socket mechanism. Depending on the data that is going to be transmitted over network(sockets), SSL may be the most important security measure of your application.

Answer (score 0):

packet sniffers could sniff unencrypted sensitive data being sent over a LAN or you could be vulnerable to ARP posisoning or MITM attacks. I strongly recommend using SSL encryption for any data being sent.